# Video Stress via Apple script

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I've been working on a video stress script based on terminal an quicktime, I'm having a specific issue with one part of playing multiple videos with quicktime as well as would love some opinions on cleaning this up/running it better

Right now the script can take up to 12 videos playing at once, it organizes them all in a single desktop, but what I'd love it to do is loop some commands that open them into full screen (presentation mode) and then bring it out. This process stresses the graphics processer and ram and processor a lot, which is why I want to do it. My code both seems inefficient and it doesn't work. I've thought about using window ID's to get a matrix of ID's to use to control them, but can't quite figure that out.

Any how here is a simplified version of my script that is just the fullscreen/unfullscreen mode. Currently it brings some of those videos out of presentation but not all of them, and not a consistant amount (some times it's 1, some times its 2 or 3) I'd really appreciate a bit of help/advice

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
set open_windows to (every window where visible is true)
set n to count of open_windows
repeat n times
    set presenting of document 1 to true
    delay 5

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
    end tell
    delay 1
end repeat

--repeat n times
try
    set presenting of document 2 to false
    delay 1

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
    end tell
    delay 1
    --end repeat
    set presenting of document 3 to false
    delay 1

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
    end tell
    delay 1
end try

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes sometimes skipped windows for me too:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    repeat with d in documents
        tell d to set presenting to true
        delay 3
    end repeat
end tell
```

You might just loop through all windows multiple times:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    repeat while presenting of documents contains false
        repeat with d in (documents where presenting is false)
            tell d to set presenting to true
            delay 3
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

You could refer to the documents with something like this:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to id of w
        tell document of w to set presenting to true
    end repeat
    window 1 where id is i
end tell
```